# No of unit cubes in a n*n*n cube

Tags: rubiks-cube

Imagine a cubic array made up of an $n\times n\times n$ arrangement of unit cubes: the cubic array is n
cubes wide, n cubes high and n cubes deep. A special case is a $3\times3\times3$ Rubik’s cube, which
you may be familiar with. How many unit cubes are there on the surface of the $n\times n\times n$ cubic array?

As far as I can see there are 27 unit cubes in a $n\times n\times n$  rubik cube. But the answer says something different. There are total $6n^2$ squares are present in $n\times n\times n$  cube. But after that I cant proceed.

Please help :)

Comment: You mean in an $n \times n \times n$ cube composite, how many cubes are there which you can see from the outside?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг exactly

Comment: In the $3\times 3\times 3$ there are $26$, all but the central cubelet.  More generally there are $n^3-(n-2)^3$, which can be written in other less informative ways.

Comment: @AndréNicolas could you please explain a bit further .. the logic why $ (n-2)^3 $ is subtracted

Comment: In the $n\times n\times n$ case, the invisible part is $(n-2)\times (n-2)\times (n-2)$, so the visible part is all $n^3$ of them except for the (n-2)^3$ invisibles.

Comment: @ViX28 see my answer for more

Comment: @AndréNicolas every time you answer I feel like my question got half solved :) thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, i think that thing you're missing is that you're counting the number of *squares* on the surface; not the number of cubes. For example, a corner piece of a Rubix cube is one cube but contributes three squares.

In a $n\times n\times n$ cube, you have the *outer layer* of cubes counting, and the ones on the inside not counting. The easiest way to see this is recursive: for a $n\times n\times n$ cube, you have an $(n-2)\times (n-2)\times (n-2)$ cube on the inside that is coated by a number of cubes that form the cubes on the outside. Subtracting $$n^3-(n-2)^3=6n^2-12n+8$$ gives the final answer.

This generalizes immediately to higher dimensions... In dimension $k$ the answer is $$n^k-(n-2)^k$$

Comment: that will be $12n$ instead of $6n$.

Comment: @ViX28 thanks! Fixed that and added the general formula

Answer (score 1):

There are $6$ faces with $n^2$ cubes on each face for a total of $6n^2$ cubes. The eight cubes on the vertices are counted $3$ times each so we must subtract $16$ to get $6n^2-16$ cubes. Likewise, there are $12$ edges, each with $n-2$ cubes that have been double counted so we must subtract $12(n-2)$ to get $6n^2-16-12n+24=6n^2-12n+8$ cubes.

Comment: More simply: $6n^2$ cubes on each face. We have counted the edges too many times, so subtract $12n$. But now we have undercounted the vertices, so add $8$ again. This gives $6n^2-12n+8$.